# Rename a txt file and keep the new name in variable?

Tags: powershell

I need to convert rename some files but I need to keep the new name in a variable so I can pass it to an array, since the name is generated using a timestamp. I can change pretty fast.

So far I was thinking in

```
$archivo=Get-Item $root\UNB\TMP\FACT_TEMPORAL.TXT | Rename-Item -NewName {("print-"+'{0:yyyy-MM-dd-hh_mm_ss}{1}' -f (Get-Date),".txt")}
```

But it wont work since it wont save the new name.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: take a look at the `-PassThru` parameter of `Rename-Item`. this `Get-Help Rename-Item -Parameter PassThru` otta help a tad. [*grin*]

Comment: That did it ! The code is the following in case someone wants to know 
$file=Get-Item $root\UNB\TMP\FACT_TEMPORAL.TXT | Rename-Item -NewName {("print-"+'{0:yyyy-MM-dd-hh_mm_ss}{1}' -f (Get-Date),".txt")} –PassThru
 $archivo=$file.Name

Comment: glad to know that it worked! [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That did it ! The code is the following in case someone wants to know

```
$file=Get-Item $root\UNB\TMP\FACT_TEMPORAL.TXT | Rename-Item -NewName {("print-"+'{0:yyyy-MM-dd-hh_mm_ss}{1}' -f (Get-Date),".txt")} –PassThru
$archivo=$file.Name
```